# C# - Lock method on value of variable (Threading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have not much experience with threading, but in this project I need some Threads to request data from a SPS over the Com-Ports. 
I have different Threads running and it could happen that 2 or even more Threads would like to access the same Com-Port, which of course doesn't work.
Now my question is if I can lock the called method on the value of a variable which would be the number of the Com-Port, while Threads with a different value can enter the Method.
Btw: I can't use different variables as "keys" for the lock, because I get the values dinamically from a database.
My code could look something like the following:

```
Main()
{
   Start different Threads calling myMethod
}

myMethod()
{
   lock on value of a Variable
   {
      some code...
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a reference type as lock-object so the _number of the Com-Port_ doesn't work. It depends on _some code..._ what you have to lock

Comment: What is question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best solution is to create a class that contains myMethod and instantiate it for each port.

If you don't want to do that you can (for example) define a thread safe dictionary of locks

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
```

initialize it before you start your threads:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    locks[i] = new object();
}
```

and lock by port number:

```
lock(locks[portnum])
{
    some code...
}
```

Assuming of course that you know the port number in the context of myMethod (otherwise how would you access the specific port?).

Comment: If `some code...` uses shared resources which aren't initialized for every port this isn't thread-safe either. Also, if this dictionary could be modified later you should use a `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: You are right! ConcurrentDictionary is the correct object to use - I edited my answer. Regarding your other point, you are correct of course, however the OP didn't specify which objects he uses so it's impossible to give a concrete example that covers all shared resources.